# WebRequestCycle.onRuntimeException redirecting to default error page

Tags: java, exception, wicket

I have 4 different error page for my wicket application. The WebRequestCycle.onRuntimeException method is:

```
@Override
public final Page onRuntimeException(Page cause, RuntimeException runtimeException) {
    if (runtimeException instanceof EMSUserNotFoundException) {
        return new EMSUserNotFoundExceptionPage(runtimeException);
    } else if (runtimeException instanceof EMSUnreachableException) {
        return new EMSUnreachableExceptionPage(runtimeException);
    } else if (runtimeException instanceof UserActionPortInitializationException) {
        return new UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage(runtimeException);
    } else {
        return new GeneralRunTimeExceptionPage(runtimeException);
    }       
}
```

In runtime EMSUserNotFoundExceptionPage, EMSUnreachableExceptionPage, GeneralRunTimeExceptionPage are displaying for corresponding cases. But the request-cycle not redirecting to the UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage. I thought UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage has some trouble so I remove GeneralRunTimeExceptionPage from else and place UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage there, then I saw that page.

Now UserActionPortInitializationException is:

```
public class UserActionPortInitializationException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10129L;

    private final static String message = "UserActionPort initialization failed";

    public UserActionPortInitializationException() {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And the code snippet that is throwing this exception is:

```
    public static String getUserActionPortAddress() {
        String userActionPortAddress = null;
        ClassPathResource userActionPortAddressResource = new ClassPathResource("port-address.properties");
        Properties properties = null;
        try {
            properties = loadProperties(userActionPortAddressResource.getFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UserActionPortInitializationException();
        }

        if (properties != null) {
            userActionPortAddress = properties.getProperty("port");
        }

        if (userActionPortAddress == null) {
            throw new UserActionPortInitializationException();
        }

        return userActionPortAddress;
    }

    private static Properties loadProperties(File file) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            props.load(is);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return props;
    }
```

When UserActionPortInitializationException is thrown by the application in console I am getting:

```
Caused by: release.exception.UserActionPortInitializationException: UserActionPort initialization failed
```

That means the exception is thrown by that snippet, but I can not understand why the page is not redirecting.

For more information:

UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage.java:

```
public class UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage extends ExceptionBasePage {

public UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage(RuntimeException runtimeException) {
    super(runtimeException);
}
```

}

UserActionPortInitializationExceptionPage.html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
<body>
    <wicket:extend>
        <h1 style="font-size: 1.5em; color: red;">UserActionPort initialization failed</h1>
        <i>Please contact administrator</i>
    </wicket:extend>
</body>
```

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your output starts with "Caused by":

```
Caused by: release.exception.UserActionPortInitializationException: UserActionPort initialization failed
```

Because of that I suppose that your Exception is wrapped by another one. And if it's wrapped, your if clause isn't able to recognize it as an `UserActionPortInitializationException`.

If you post the full stack trace, I could verify my assumption.